# Trying to iterate through a DataGridView by Selected row; Receiving Index out of Bounds

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I originally created a foreach DGVrow to iterate through the DGV, but this would take long since it iterates through the entire data grid which contains thousands of rows. I switched up the for each into the following:

```
        if (DGVmain.RowCount > 0)
        {
            if (DGVmain.SelectedCells.Count <= 0)
            {
                return;
            }
            //Source
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog.Filter = "Excel Files|*.xls;*.xlsx";
            openFileDialog.ShowDialog();
            lblSuccess.Text = openFileDialog.FileName;
            lblPathings = Path.ChangeExtension(openFileDialog.FileName, null);
            int count = DGVmain.SelectedRows.Count;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow selectedRow in DGVmain.SelectedRows)
            {
                //Drag
                if (lblSuccess.Text == null)
                    return;
                //Drag
                if (lblSuccess.Text == null)
                    return;
                string dragsy = Convert.ToString(selectedRow.Cells[1].Value);
                string drag = Convert.ToString(selectedRow.Cells[2].Value);
                string drag2 = Convert.ToString(selectedRow.Cells[3].Value);
                string drag3 = Convert.ToString(selectedRow.Cells[4].Value);
                string drag4 = Convert.ToString(selectedRow.Cells[5].Value);
                string drag5 = Convert.ToString(selectedRow.Cells[6].Value);
                string drag6 = Convert.ToString(selectedRow.Cells[7].Value);
                string drag7 = Convert.ToString(selectedRow.Cells[8].Value);
                string drag8 = Convert.ToString(selectedRow.Cells[9].Value);
                string drag9 = Convert.ToString(selectedRow.Cells[10].Value);
                string drag10 = Convert.ToString(selectedRow.Cells[11].Value);
                Persona = drag;
                generateID();
                }
            }
        }
```

I cut out the part with where the function manipulates the data to insert it into an Excel file. It's not throwing an error, so I assume everything is sound with the syntax arrangement? What's wrong with this loop?

I only receive an index is out of bounds of the array.

Comment: Probably there's no `Cells[11]`.I guess cells should go from 0 to 10

Comment: Ah, are DataGridViews 0 based?

Comment: In c#,all arrays are 0 based

Comment: In that case, change this to an answer, and I'll accept it! Guess I wasted my question every 40 minutes... still have to ask one on how to remove duplicates from an excel column properly.

Comment: Well, you don't have to wait too much :)

Comment: @Arvayne: As a debugging tip if you'd just looked at the values you were getting out of the array I would assume you'd have noticed it was missing out the first column and that `Cells[10]` was the last column. When you get a bug look at the code that it is running, look at the array to see if it has the columns you want, etc. That should have saved you needing to ask at all!

Comment: @Chris totally agree. How to debug should be the first thing a coder should learn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C#,all arrays are 0 based. So the problem must be that you are trying to access from `selectedRow.Cells[1]` to `selectedRow.Cells[11]`, when you should use `selectedRow.Cells[0]`to `selectedRow.Cells[10]`